# Is it possible to find the edit history of a tag?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

I would like to see the edit history of a tag. That is who edited what and when they did it. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Go to the information page of the tag (e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/support/info) and click either 'history' or 'excerpt history'. You will find the same kind of revision history as for normal posts.

[image: tag information page with links to history]

[image: revision history for tag]

Comment: Had to switch to my "reputable" account. All that's hidden if you don't have the privileges. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just click the "history" link on the tag info page:

[image]